# Name for SELECT * FROM (VALUES (x,y)) AS TableLiteral(Col1, Col2)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, terminology

The following is valid SQL syntax:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('p','q'),('x','y')) AS TableLiteral(Col1, Col2)
```

and returns the table:

```
  | Col1 | Col2
----------------
1 |  p   |  q
2 |  x   |  y
```

This syntax can further be used in CTEs etc.

Is there a name for this?
I've been calling them "TableLiterals" by analogy with string literals and regex literals.

Is there a term that will be widely recognised.

Comment: [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)

Comment: I think you are looking for table value constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called: **[Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)**

> Specifies a set of row value expressions to be constructed into a table. The Transact-SQL table value constructor allows multiple rows of data to be specified in a single DML statement. **The table value constructor can be specified in the VALUES clause of the INSERT statement, in the USING  clause of the MERGE statement, and in the definition of a derived table in the FROM clause.**
>
> VALUES (  ) [ ,...n ]

More info about ANSI standard: [F641, Row and table constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh501301(v=sql.105).aspx) and 
[select without from](http://modern-sql.com/use-case/select-without-from)

Answer (score 2):

They are called Table Value constructor

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql