# Performance with Table-Valued Constructors in CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

(Hat-tip to answers over here for the terminology: [Name for SELECT * FROM (VALUES (x,y)) AS TableLiteral(Col1, Col2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466558/name-for-select-from-values-x-y-as-tableliteralcol1-col2/45466642#45466642). Many thanks.)

I have a large and complex query (multiple CTEs, CTEs referring back to earlier CTEs, WINDOWing functions, some very verbose WHERE clauses, etc.)

The data has 2 string-based state columns, `Foo` and `Bar`
At one point I break the rows into 3 categories:

- Category A (based on a verbose set of multiple if "`Foo` = `x` and `Bar` in (`p`,`r`,`t`)" or if ...)
- Category B (based on a different, and disjoint, but still verbose set of similar conditions.)
- Category C (Everything else)

On a medium sized dataset (100k rows), a version of the query which involved defining C as

```
SELECT * FROM ALL
EXCEPT
(
  SELECT * FROM A
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM B
)
```

ran in 21 seconds.

---

Then I tried a version of the query which repeated the constraints from A & B, but NOT-ing them.
That ran in a more pleasant 6 seconds, but is obviously very WET.

---

Then I considered trying to try the whole thing out a lot further and defined this CTE, using a TableValued Constructor to define the Category for any given pair of `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
WITH StateTransitions AS (
SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
         ('x','p', 'A'),
         ('x','q', 'B'),
         ('x','r', 'A'),
         ('x','s', 'B'),
         ('x','t', 'A'),

         ('y','p', 'A'),
         ('y','q', 'A'),
         ('y','r', 'B'),
         ('y','s', 'B'),
         ('y','t', 'B'),

         ('z','p', 'C'),
         ('z','q', 'B'),
         ('z','r', 'A'),
         ('z','s', 'A'),
         ('z','t', 'B'),

    ) AS TableLiteral(Foo, Bar, Category)
),
rest of query.
```

and JOINed relevant columns together and defined my category CTEs based on the Category column from those JOINs.

Great! Nice and DRY.

Except now it runs in **28.5 *minutes***

---

What gives!?
Why does using a TVC seem to have tanked the performance *so* badly.

I recognise that this might be considered an X-Y problem, and if anyone wants to give opinions on how to design the query as a whole, then I'm happy to go into further detail elsewhere. But right now I do *actually* want to know what's up with the performance. I consider myself moderately competent at SQL and the performance difference was a complete shock.

---

EDIT: Query plans might be forthcoming, if I can convince the company to give me SHOWPLAN permissions.

Comment: Statistics, wrong cardinality estimation. Guessing. Please post query execution plan.

Comment: You can use the following for execution plan sharing: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: :0 Wow how has this tool never been mentioned to me!

Comment: will generate and upload.

Comment: dammit. Don't have SHOWPLAN permission for the DB where this happened. And on a similar database with a comparable table, it only takes 6 seconds to run. Will try to acquire permissions and edit question when that's available.

Comment: Writing out the expressions produces a big old syntax tree that the optimizer may run through rather inefficiently, but valiantly. Using a table constructor, however, produces a table with no statistics. It's extremely simple to end up with terrible queries. For starters, see what happens if you insert that data in a temp table and use that in your CTE (even if you cannot use that in production because you must have a single query). Is it still 28 minutes or is it magically faster? Is it faster still when you put an index on `(Foo, Bar)`?

Comment: Just for fun, does anything change if you include `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the query with the TVC, even though it logically shouldn't since the text is static?

Comment: CTEs can't take `OPTION` hints,  and applying it to the whole query doesn't do anything.

Comment: OK. I asked because table variables are also notorious for producing bad query plans based on missing statistics, and there `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` actually convinces the optimizer to count rows (even though this isn't documented). I thought it unlikely something similar would happen for table value constructors, but it couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: Another thing worth experimenting with is `CROSS APPLY` on a `SelectCategory(Foo, Bar)` inline TVF, and a non-inline TVF. (And a scalar function if you must, but that will be horrible.)

Comment: Functions, Sprocs etc. are not permitted unless literally no other solution is possible. :(    Not my house; Not my rules.